# create a nested map using hashmap in java to accomplish the nested array but not working

Tags: java, arrays, selenium

I want to create a nested array like in php. But someone told it is not available in Java and tell to use map and hash map. So I have tried following to accomplish this issue

```
List<WebElement> address = driver.findElements(By.xpath(addressXpath));
List<WebElement> addressPrimaryList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(addressPrimaryXpath));
List<WebElement> addressSecondryList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(addressSecondryXpath));
List<WebElement> addressLocationList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(addressLocationXpath));

Map<String, String> addresses = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> addressesParent = new HashMap<String, String>();

int totalAdd = address.size();
System.out.println("Total addresses are " + totalAdd);
for (int i = 0; i < totalAdd; i++) {                            

     addressesParent.put("'" + i + "'", addresses.put("addressPrimary", addressPrimaryList.get(i).getText()));
     addressesParent.put("'" + i + "'", addresses.put("addressSecondry", addressSecondryList.get(i).getText()));
     addressesParent.put("'" + i + "'", addresses.put("addressLocation", addressLocationList.get(i).getText()));
}

// addresses.get("addressPrimary"); // returns "addressPrimary value"
System.out.println(addresses.toString());
System.out.println(addressesParent.toString());
```

It gives me following results

```
{addressSecondry=Apt B, addressLocation=Merrick, NY 11566-3559, addressPrimary=1964 Stuyvesant Ave}

{'0'=null, '1'=Merrick, NY 11566-4523}
```

But I want results like some thing in php
 
Note: following php code is just example I want to something similar

```
 $addresses[0]['primary'] = $primaryaddress; 
 $addresses[0]['secondy'] = $secondryaddress; 
 $addresses[0]['location'] = $locationaddress;


 $addresses[1]['primary'] = $primaryaddress; 
 $addresses[1]['secondy'] = $secondryaddress; 
 $addresses[1]['location'] = $locationaddress;
```

Comment: I think you need something like a list of maps: `List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();`

Comment: can you please tell me how to use it in for loop? because I am new to java and already banging head from couple of hours. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making the wrong approach. You should encapsulate the data in an object and create a list (or array) of these objects. Like:

```
public class Address {

    private String addressPrimary, addressSecondry, addressLocation;

    public void setAddressPrimary(String ap) {
        addressPrimary = ap;
    }

    public String getAddressPrimary() {
        return addressPrimary;
    }

    public void setAddressSecondry(String as) {
        addressSecondry = as;
    }

    public String getAddressSecondry() {
        return addressSecondry;
    }

    public void setAddressLocation(String al) {
        addressLocation = al;
    }

    public String getAddressLocation() {
        return addressLocation;
    }

}
```

Merged with your code it would look like:

```
List<WebElement> address = driver.findElements(By.xpath(addressXpath));
List<WebElement> addressPrimaryList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(addressPrimaryXpath));
List<WebElement> addressSecondryList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(addressSecondryXpath));
List<WebElement> addressLocationList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(addressLocationXpath));

int totalAdd = address.size();

System.out.println("Total addresses are " + totalAdd);

List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < totalAdd; i++) {
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setAddressPrimary(addressPrimaryList.get(i).getText());
    address.setAddressSecondry(addressSecondryList.get(i).getText());
    address.setAddressLocation(addressLocationList.get(i).getText());
    addresses.add(address);
}
```

You would access the data like following:

```
addresses.get(0).getAddressPrimary();
//        ^      ^
//        |      |
//        Returns an Address object
//               |
//               Returns the addressPrimary property
```

You could also work with maps but I think that it is bad style and the wrong approach:

```
List<WebElement> address = driver.findElements(By.xpath(addressXpath));
List<WebElement> addressPrimaryList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(addressPrimaryXpath));
List<WebElement> addressSecondryList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(addressSecondryXpath));
List<WebElement> addressLocationList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(addressLocationXpath));

int totalAdd = address.size();

System.out.println("Total addresses are " + totalAdd);

List<Map<String, String> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < totalAdd; i++) {
    Map<String, String> address = new HashMap<>();
    address.put("addressPrimary", addressPrimaryList.get(i).getText());
    address.put("addressSecondry", addressSecondryList.get(i).getText());
    address.put("addressLocation", addressLocationList.get(i).getText());
    addresses.add(address);
}
```

Then you access data with:

```
addresses.get(0).get("addressPrimary");
```

I don't recommend this.

Comment: thanks for answer I have create an package name myaddress and create a class within Myaddress.java init. Then import it in main class and follow your code and **System.out.println(addresses.toString());** it shows me **[myaddress.Myaddress@1b13588, myaddress.Myaddress@1317ccb]** is it right result?

Comment: Thanks its working **for (Myaddress myaddress : addresses) {
        
        System.out.println(myaddress.getAddressLocation());
       }**

Comment: please plus 1 to my question :)

Comment: Yes this is correct. You could override the `toString()` method in your `Myaddress` class. the you would get custom output.

Comment: how can I convert **List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();** to json srting object to store this array in database?

Comment: This is a very common question. Just google for it or search on SO.